# Argparse tutorial example doesn't work in windows command line

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

So I'm trying to teach myself how to use the python library `argparse` via the tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). The example is given by the following piece of code which is saved as `tut.py`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                const=sum, default=max,
                help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

In the tutorial they put a `$` before every command in the command line which is due to them using Linux I think. First if I add an `$` in my windows command line before any command I get the error

```
The "$" command was either misspelled or could not be found.
```

If I then run

```
 python tut.py 1 2 3 4
```

I don't get an error but neither is any output displayed in the command line. What would be expected is the sum of those integers though.

How can I make the output show up in the command prompt ?

Comment: The `$` just denotes a new line in the linux terminal, you can ignore it

Comment: What happens if you set `print(args.accumulate(args.integers), flush=True)`?

Comment: If you want to print sum of the integers, try sum() function instead of accumulate()

Comment: @HirushaFernando OP wants to leverage the default set by the `--sum` flag, which is `max`, and if the `sum` flag is passed, it will switch to `sum` as seen by the `const` and `default` kwargs, so `args.accumulate` is correct

Comment: @C.Nivs setting flush = True doesn't generate any output neither

Comment: Can you try running `python -u -c "print('hello')"` and see if it prints anything? The `-u` is for unbuffered output

Comment: There is still no output

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning I didn't think that it was important to specify that I use the *anaconda* distribution for python, however it turns out that using the anaconda command prompt instead of the windos 10 one solves the problem.

#### Output

```
(base) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\HiWi\Codect>python tut.py 1 2 3 4
4

(base) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\HiWi\Codect>python tut.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
10

(base) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\HiWi\Codect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get some of n passed arguments :
tut.py

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                const=sum, default=max,
                help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(sum(args.integers))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
python tut.py 1 2 3 4   
10
```

Note: when I run your code it runs perfectly

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It still doesn't show any output in my case

Comment: Actually, it does. I ran the same script in my windows 10 machine and this worked. Check your cmd command

Comment: try `echo hi` in cmd. does it print something?

Comment: Yes it prints "hi"

Comment: Now make a python script which simply prints hi by `print('hi')` and run by cmd. Does it print anything?

Comment: in this case I don't get any output

Comment: Try : if __name__ == "__main__":   main() and put all code in main() function

Comment: This doesn't work neither. Apparently the problem is not related with argparse though since even print("hi") doesn't yield any output

Comment: Yes, ask a new question about the same in `Ask Question`

Comment: @YashMakan OP does not have to ask a new question, your answer just doesn't answer this one