# Running python file in command line yields no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

After deliberating about this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200894/argparse-tutorial-example-doesnt-work-in-windows-command-line?noredirect=1#comment115269417_65200894) it looks like something is wrong with my command prompt.

Even the file called `test.py` containing the following code

```
 print("hi")
```

doesn't lead to any output being shown when called in my command prompt on windows 10

#### Output

```
C:\Users\Admin>python test.py

C:\Users\Admin>
```

Meaning nothing is printed.

As suggested in my original question I also tried running

```
python -u -c "print('hello')"
```

Which doesn't yield any output neither.

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364487/python3-print-statement-not-showing-any-output-on-the-command-line) concerned with the same problem, however doesn't have any answers yet.

Comment: Should it spell "from" or "in" command line in the heading ?

Comment: Either word would work. And you're saying that when you run `C:\Users\Admin>python test.py`, all it does is take you to the next line a print `C:\Users\Admin>` again? Or does it hang?

Comment: It doesn't hang. There is a blank space and then it take me to the next line. I edited my post accordingly

Comment: I'd just completely uninstall the interpreter and reinstall the latest version. I don't know what exactly the issue is, but a reinstall never hurts.

Comment: I use anaconda if that is of any concern

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using the command prompt doesn't work, however I've been using the *anaconda* distribution for python and using the anaconda command prompt instead of the windows 10 one solves the problem.

#### Output

```
(base) C:\Users\Admin>python test.py
hi

(base) C:\Users\Admin>
```